# R melting/gathering file with 2 heading rows into attributes

Tags: r, tidyverse, melt

I need to read in a datafile with 2 levels of headers, the data looks like this:

```
|          | Jone Doe |      |      |      |      |      |      | Jane Doe |      |      |      |      |      |      | 
|----------|----------|------|------|------|------|------|------|----------|------|------|------|------|------|------| 
| Date     | Col1     | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col1     | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | 
| 1-Jul-13 | 49       | 42   | 20   | 18   | 23   | 16   | 29   | 48       | 33   | 24   | 10   | 43   | 13   | 43   | 
| 2-Jul-13 | 17       | 16   | 43   | 33   | 37   | 37   | 10   | 7        | 45   | 19   | 4    | 41   | 41   | 20   | 
| 3-Jul-13 | 35       | 39   | 42   | 35   | 5    | 12   | 22   | 3        | 28   | 23   | 10   | 12   | 5    | 8    |
```

I need it to look like this:

```
| Date     | Name     | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | 
|----------|----------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------| 
| 1-Jul-13 | Jone Doe | 49   | 42   | 20   | 18   | 23   | 16   | 29   | 
| 2-Jul-13 | Jone Doe | 17   | 16   | 43   | 33   | 37   | 37   | 10   | 
| 3-Jul-13 | Jone Doe | 35   | 39   | 42   | 35   | 5    | 12   | 22   | 
| 1-Jul-13 | Jane Doe | 48   | 33   | 24   | 10   | 43   | 13   | 43   | 
| 2-Jul-13 | Jane Doe | 7    | 45   | 19   | 4    | 41   | 41   | 20   | 
| 3-Jul-13 | Jane Doe | 3    | 28   | 23   | 10   | 12   | 5    | 8    |
```

Any idea on how to do this without hard-coding? I've been trying using melt() and gather() without any luck

Edit:

Sample data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T4KkAk5D55_nXsHlr1Aozed6d49qFM_8

Output of lst1:
[image]

output of nm1:

```
 [1] "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "John Doe"  "Jane Doe" 
 [9] "Jane Doe"  "Jane Doe"  "Jane Doe"  "Jane Doe"  "Jane Doe"  "Jane Doe"  "Jose Doe"  "Jose Doe" 
[17] "Jose Doe"  "Jose Doe"  "Jose Doe"  "Jose Doe"  "Jose Doe"  "Jacob Doe" "Jacob Doe" "Jacob Doe"
[25] "Jacob Doe" "Jacob Doe" "Jacob Doe" "Jacob Doe"
```

Comment: Looks like your 'nm1' is right.  Let me check with your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to read the dataset with `skip` argument to skip the 1st row, then, we can `split` the data into a `list` based on the duplicate column names and then create the 'Name' column for each `list` element based on the first row and `rbind` the `list` elements to create a single data.frame

```
dat1 <- read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, skip = 1, 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "N/A")
nm1 <- c("John Doe", "Jane Doe")[cumsum(grepl("Col1", names(dat1)[-1]))]
 nm2 <- unique( sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(dat1)[-1]))
lst1 <- split.default(dat1[-1], nm1)
dat2 <- cbind(dat1['Date'], do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Name = nm1,  lapply(lst1, setNames, nm2))))
row.names(dat2) <- NULL
head(dat2, 5)
#      Date     Name Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7
#1 1-Jul-13 John Doe   52    6   NA   NA    7   20   25
#2 2-Jul-13 John Doe   43    7   NA   NA   NA   25   17
#3 3-Jul-13 John Doe   55    5   NA   NA    4   23   28
#4 4-Jul-13 John Doe   42    6   NA   NA    7   21   14
#5 5-Jul-13 John Doe   64    3   NA   NA    5   36   22

dim(dat2)
#[1] 140   9
```

---

Note that if the number of blocks of columns are large, an option is to read the first line with `readLines`

```
v1 <- readLines("file.csv", n = 1)
v2 <- scan(text = gsub(",{2,}", ",", trimws(v1)), sep=",", what = "", quiet = TRUE)
v3 <- v2[nzchar(v2)]
```

and feed it to the `cumsum` step

```
nm1 <- v3[cumsum(grepl("Col1", names(dat1)[-1]))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried this and get the following error ```Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names``` on this line ```dat2 <- cbind(dat1['Date'], do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Name = nm1, lst1)))```. Inspecting lst1 i think it is nearly there

Comment: It looks like the names in ```lst1``` have a '.1', '.2','.3', etc... appended onto it

Comment: @zaza Can you update your post with the `lst1` as `dput` for the small example.  As I don't have the correct structure, it may be some minor issue

Comment: @zaza What is the output for 'nm1'

Comment: I've updated the question with sample data and requested info

Comment: @zaza Okay, I understand the issue